# Get URL To Full Size Image And Add It To Specific Word In A Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hyperlink a specific word in the post to the full image which is stored on `wp-content/uploads`.

I add a line of words "View Full Size" on `single.php` so it is displayed on the bottom of each created post and I want to hyperlink those words to the full size image attached on that post.

How to do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this snippet a couple times, It grabs the featured image, I've added the else option so you can set a default image if needed. I hope this is what you where looking for. Any problems I'll be glad to help.

```
<?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) : ?>
  <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );  $alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);?> 
  <a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View Full Size</a>
<?php else: ?>

<?php endif;?>
```